# std::istream ends unexpectedly

Tags: c++, stream, istream

I am trying to read a binary file in chunks. The file is approximately 11 kB. The following code reads from the file only once and the `gcount()` function says that only 1015 characters (bytes) were read and the stream is „depleted“ and the while loop does not continue (although the buffer is filled correctly up to `buffer[4095]`):

```
std::array<int64_t, 256>  HuffmanTree::get_frequencies(std::istream & stream) const
{
    const size_t buffer_size = 4096;
    unsigned char buffer[buffer_size];
    std::array<int64_t, 256> frequencies;
    frequencies.fill(0);

    while (stream)
    {
        stream.read((char *)buffer, buffer_size);
        std::streamsize bytes_read = stream.gcount();

        for (std::streamsize i = 0; i < bytes_read; i++)
        {
            frequencies[buffer[i]]++;
        }
    }

    return frequencies;
}
```

What causes this behaviour and how could I fix it?

Edit: The `stream.read(...)` is called only ONCE and `gcount()` returns 1015. But the buffer contains the first 4096 bytes of the file (also I am running on Windows - VS 2017)

Comment: I was unable to reproduce.  The input file I mocked up was approximately 11 kB, and the routine was able to input every byte of the file.  I don't know why yours is reading 1015 bytes for the last buffer chunk rather than ~3072 bytes.  If you were running on Windows, then I could hazard a guess (i.e., the istream was not in binary mode).  Or if it was an input stream like a pipe or an open socket.

Comment: Well that is weird then. Also the problem is that the read() function is called only ONCE so I get only the first 4096 bytes of the file and never anything else. The stream the ends saying that it has read 1015 bytes. But the buffer contains 4096 bytes from the file. The rest of the file is never read. Also how to open a istream in binary mode? And what to do if it does not matter to me if the input file is binary or text?

Comment: What is your platform?  What C++ compiler are you using?  What compiler version are you using?  Can you reproduce with a [mcve]?  Have you tried to step through the code with a debugger?

Comment: Edited the question. I have tried to step through and that is when I found out that the read function is called only once. I do not understand why would that happen (and why would it fill the buffer correctly and say it had read only 1015 bytes).

Comment: "And what to do if it does not matter to me if the input file is binary or text?" On a Windows platform, files processed as text will process and interpret and translate the characters.  Possibly the input file has a "end of file" character at position 1016.

Comment: @Eljay Now I was able to open the file with std::ios::binary and it works as it should. If you'd like to write this as an answer I will accept it. I did not know about this distinction in c++ whether I am working with binary or text file.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem comes when you've less than 4096 bytes to read, and you call `stream.read()`

I use the following function, which TRIES to read 4096, but tidies up when it fails - maybe it's of use?

```
// Tries to read num bytes from inRaw into buffer (space previously allocated).  When num bytes does not take
// us off the end of the file, then this does the simple obvious thing and returns true.  When num bytes takes
// us over the edge, but things are still sane (they wanted 100 bytes, only 60 bytes to go), then this fills
// as much as possible and leaves things in a nice clean state.  When there are zero bytes to go, this
// return false.
bool safeRead(
    std::ifstream& inRaw,
    char* buffer,
    uint16_t num
)
{
    auto before = inRaw.tellg();
    if (inRaw.read(buffer, num) && inRaw.good() && !inRaw.eof())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        if (inRaw.gcount())
        {
            inRaw.clear();
            auto pos = before + std::streamoff(inRaw.gcount());
            inRaw.seekg(pos);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But my file is 11 kB and it never gets to the point where I would have less than 4096 bytes to read. The while loop does not repeat after the first read (although 4096 bytes have been read, it stops reading saying that only 1015 bytes have been read).

Comment: You're not reading 4096 twice and then finding less than 4096 to read?

Comment: No, when stepping through the function the stream.read(...) is called only once. So my buffer contains only the first 4096 bytes of the file and never nothing else. What I do not understand is why the stream ends when I did not read the rest and why does the gcount() return 1015 when it sucessfully read 4096 bytes.

Comment: Sounds like it did NOT successfully read 4096; it read only 1015 and ran out of file ... sure you gave it an 11kb file?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. The buffer contains first 4096 bytes of the file. So how is that possible?

Comment: Have you tried using the func I provided and seeing where it goes inside that?